# Prevent vertical lines border display while scrolling jqxgrid horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

How to avoid displaying vertical border lines while scrolling jqxgrid horizontally..That is I found that till grid width it is displaying correctly.

The above issue displaying after GROUPING done in jqxgrid[image]